# Nativescript : get page object outside loaded function

Tags: nativescript

javascript:

```
...
//I want use page object outside the loded function
var page

exports.loaded =function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;

    //there is already a 'grid9' element in XML file 
    var gridLayout = page.getViewById("grid9");

    if(gridLayout ) alert("yes");//<============it works
}
if (page.getViewById("grid9"))  alert("yes");//<========== got error
```

I want use `page` object outside the `loaded` function.In my mind,`page` is defined outside the `loaded` fuction,then the `page` variable get the real `page` object in the funtion,so I can use the `page` object outside the function right now.
But,I got a error of `undefined` .And ,without the second `if` statement ,it goes well.
If I met a variable scope mistake or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem with your if is that it will execute before loaded function because its outside of functions so its executte immediately at loading of file so either you put that `if` somewhere to function or try use this to get current page outside of loaded function

```
var frameModule=require("ui/frame");
var page = frameModule.topmost().currentPage;
```

but if its still outside `exports.foo = function(){}` it's not sure that it will page object